# ABN tree performance issue in IE with big list

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using ABN tree.Below is the code

```
<ul class="nav nav-list nav-pills nav-stacked abn-tree">

    <li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'"
        ng-class="'level-' + {{ row.level }} + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row">
</li>
</ul>
```

But the data is tree_rows is big and it is trying to loop through all the children and construct tree and it has performance hit in IE.

Is it possible to load all the parent nodes first once we click on expand, it constructs children from the list.

Any help on this is so much apprecaited

Comment: Please make a sample showing the issue in action if you need to generate a lot of fake data just use a loop or an online JSON generator.  Always difficult to give answers on performance issues since it depends what is the worst part in terms of efficiency where you'll get the greatest gain.  In general yes you can create new elements on the fly only when needed, and you should only really have as many elements created as can fit on screen or in your control/viewport area for a component.

Answer (score 0):

ABN tree have performance issue in Internet Explorer with big list. I couldn't find any solution to fix it.

I have removed ABN tree and constructed my own tree using Directives